# How to display iPhone MapView ZoomIn by default?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am trying to implement UIMapView and I did this task successfully but I want by default ZoomIn mapview at certain ratio how can I implement this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = 0.4; 
        span.longitudeDelta = 0.4;
```

Here
    latitudeDelta (the vertical distance represented by the region), and
    longitudeDelta (the horizontal distance represented by the region).

You can find more details about [MKMapview here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/)
BTW it is not UIMapView it is MKMapView...

Comment: This is not helpful for me. Thank you

Comment: without seeing your code i cant able to answer your question correctly. post some of your codes..